# RecyclerView or ScrollView in XML?

Tags: android, xml

This question is for using others experience.
I have a screen with a lot of settings. Some of the Settings are the same. How would you implement it using a `RecyclerView` or `ScrollView` or another way?

[image]

Comment: yes I think you go with recycler view

Comment: Go with `RecyclerView`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use `ScrollView` because you would need implement many logic and holders in your `RecyclerView`. Also it will be good to create custom compound **View** to reuse it, and no to copy paste a lot of same code in one xml (no includes can be used) because you will need different View id's.

**ALSO**: `RecyclerView` is used to create lists of unkonwn size, it is not usable to create static screen, even with many items.

Comment: I agree, also in my opinion it should be `ScrollView`. You can separate code on modules to avoid duplicate code. Modules like "days picker module", "seek bar module", even "title module" and "title with button module". Write some setters to each module and reuse them on ScrollView. Should be much easier than RecyclerView.